# Group by and assign it to intermediate groups in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the pandas dataframe in the below format. For every group in col1, I am trying to compute the average of 'price' and assign it to the same group but for year '2015'(in Result dataframe below). That result has to be added to the original dataframe.

I have tried this but not sure how to assign the intermediate results by creating a separate row for it.

```
df_make_year.apply(lambda x: x.groupby('Col1')['price'].mean())


col1    year    price

XXX     2016    4633.028506
XXX     2017    4805.72567
YYY     2016    4919.385966
YYY     2017    4959.816429
YYY     2018    4987.046863
```

Result(added to the above dataframe):

```
XXX 2015    4719
YYY 2015    4955
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `append` after `groupby` `assign`

```
df = df.append(df.groupby('col1').agg({'col1':'first', 'price':'mean'}).assign(year=2015).reset_index(drop=True),sort=True)
```